# Can I make statements with structure like "我这个“老外”这么喜欢看京剧"?

Tags: sentence-structure

My textbook has this sentence.

> 我这个“老外”这么喜欢看京剧，老师当然感到很惊讶。

I notice it has a a bit different structure.

> 我这个“老外”这么喜欢看京剧
>   = I,a foreigner, really like watch Peking Opera = Subject + Subject description + Do something.

**So can I make any statements with this structure?**

E.g: 我妹妹，一个漂亮的女孩，很喜欢买衣服。
     他爸爸，一个老师，教我学书法。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Subject + Subject description + Do something is understandable to me.

And if you could use some conjunctions based on the scenario, then the sentence would be more beautiful.

For example, His father, a P.E teacher, but teaches me for handwriting.
他爸爸，一位体育老师，但是却能教我书法。

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can. And people can understand what you me. When I read from left to right 我妹妹，一個漂亮的女孩 I can understand 一個漂亮的女孩 is used to describe 我妹妹 since the context and only ， between them.

I think if you want to make it more clear, you can use 是個 or 是一個 to substitute 一個 because it help to link them together. 是 is used to denote things that is other things. So A is B in traditional Chinese is A是B. So you use 是 or 是一個 can help to link 我妹妹 with 漂亮的女孩 and 他爸爸 with 一個老師 together.

Comment: My full sentence is 我妹妹，一个漂亮的女孩，很喜欢买衣服。So, if I add 是 between 我妹妹 and 一个漂亮的女孩, it would be a new sentence. Of course, the predicate 很喜欢买衣服 may be separated (from my initial sentence) into a new one. It becomes:
我妹妹 是 一个漂亮的女孩. 她 很喜欢买衣服. Do I understand in a correct way?

Comment: I think both of 我妹妹 是一個漂亮的女孩 很喜歡買衣服 and 我妹妹 是一個漂亮的女孩 她很喜歡買衣服 are ok. Because I can interpret both of them as same meaning, since 她 means 我妹妹. And if I don't add 她. 很喜歡買衣服 is used to describe 我妹妹 too. So I think both of add 她 or not add 她 is ok in this situation.

Comment: Thanks. I know in terms of speaking, you can understand the meaning. However, in the exam, is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: I really don't know whether or not it is grammatically correct because I don't know their standard to determine whether or not it is right.